# Oracle 11G export error (Ora-01115: IO Error reading block from file 6 (block $ 75593959)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have oracle 11G installed on Windows 2008 Server. I have a big file table space of 700GB. I have all the data/tables in a single user "ARCHIVE". While exporting the database with `exp` command. It produces the following errors:

```
EXP-00056: ORACLE error 1115 encountered
ORA-01115: IO Error reading block from file 6 (block # 75593959)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
ORA-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 23) Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
```

What is the safe method to export my database?

```
===================expdp output starts=========================
;;; 
Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 18 09:19:59 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "ARCHIVE"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02":  archive/******** schemas=archive directory=backup_dir dumpfile=bck_180915 logfile=expdplog compression=all 
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 703.8 GB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
ORA-31693: Table data object "ARCHIVE"."TBL_MATRIC_DATA" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 6 (block # 54124632)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 23) Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 6 (block # 54124632)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous
ORA-31693: Table data object "ARCHIVE"."TBL_INTER_DATA" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 6 (block # 75593959)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous I/O request.
O/S-Error: (OS 23) Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
ORA-01115: IO error reading block from file 6 (block # 75593959)
ORA-27070: async read/write failed
OSD-04016: Error queuing an asynchronous 
. . exported "ARCHIVE"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"            31.76 KB    1122 rows
. . exported "ARCHIVE"."MISSING_RANGES"                  5.984 KB     102 rows
. . exported "ARCHIVE"."RANGES"                          4.968 KB      10 rows
Master table "ARCHIVE"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for ARCHIVE.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02 is:
  BCK_180915.DMP
Job "ARCHIVE"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_02" completed with 2 error(s) at 20:38:19

====================expdp output ends =========================
```

Comment: Why do you use old EXP on 11g? Use data pump EXPDP. Also, copy paste and post the exact command line you used. `Cause:     Device on which the file resides is probably offline
Action:     Restore access to the device`

Comment: I have tried to backup with expdp command too, complete command is:
expdp archive schemas=archive directory=backup_dir dumpfile=bck_180915 logfile=expdplog compression=all
but still gives the same errors, the complete output is given above in the question, plz check.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude this one table (TBL_INTER_DATA) and try again. You can try save non damaged part of content TBL_INTER_DATA to CSV file (use row number for finding and skipping damaged blocks) if TBL_INTER_DATA is important for you.

Comment: TBL_INTER_DATA is important, but the problem is how to find the damaged rows of the block as mentioned above.

Comment: I may suggest binary search, something like `select * from TBL_INTER_DATA where rownum<X` where initial X= row_count/2